# How to use setw(x) in a toString method in c++ and put it in a variable or suggestions?

Tags: c++, class, oop, setw

I have a Book class, and I want to implement a toString method in c++, using setw(x), to format in a properly mode.

I want to print something like that:

```
> cout<<setw(10)<<book.title<<setw(10)<<book.author;
```

but in a toString method:

```
string toString(){
 string buff;
 .... 
 return buff; }
```

Thanks!

Comment: And your *specific* question is?

Comment: How can i use setw in the toString method?

Comment: String streams exist: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/sstream

Comment: it's something like sprintf as i saw, true?

Comment: Ehh, no. Not really. `sprintf` and iostream may achieve the same end result, but they are used and implemented rather differently. Btw; you already used the `std::cout` stream - the string stream is similar. It's quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::ostringstream`, eg:

```
#include <sstream>

string toString() const {
    std::ostringstream buff;
    buff << std::setw(10) << title << std::setw(10) << author;
    return buff.str();
}
```

```
cout << book.toString()
```